# asp.net membership db changes not committing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

When a user registers, I set the IsApproved value to false until later. After "approval" I set the users .IsApproved=true. However, the change does not get committed to db. It does show change in debugging. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```

... That should force an update of the user after you set the flag.

[MSDN Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.updateuser.aspx)

Comment: ah crap, at least second brain fart tonight. time for sleep. THANKS.

Comment: lol don't feel bad, I should be asleep right now, glad it worked for you, goodnight!